# Wordpress Shortcode in Menu Item Title

Tags: menus

I've looked and have not found anything that works.

I am trying to include a shortcode in a menu item's 'Navigation Label'. Basically Iwould like to have a dynamic title displaying the user's name & avatar.

```
[profilepicture round] [user_name]
```

Right now it's just spit back out since Wordpress Menus do not parse shortcodes. I've tried:

```
function my_nav_menu_objects_shortcode_mangler($items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
       $item->title = do_shortcode($item->title);
    }
    return $items;
}
```

But it doesn't parse it. I also tried $item->type_label with no luck. Am I just referencing the wrong attribute of item?

Also tried the following with no luck.

```
 add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'do_shortcode');
```

The avatar and username can both be retrieved via php if needed:

```
<?php echo userpro_profile_data('user_login', $user_id); ?>
<?php echo userpro_profile_data('profilepicture', $user_id); ?>
```

Comment: This could be theme specific if your theme uses a custom nav menu walker. Can you confirm whether it uses the default WP nav menu walker?

Comment: Also, what kind of menu item is it (link? page? post? other?) and where are you entering the shortcode (as the nav label? title? other?)?

Answer (score 5):

Since WP 4.4.0 you can use the following:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_item_title', function ($title, $item, $args, $depth) {
    return do_shortcode($title);
}, 10, 4);
```

Comment: as far as I understand, this is a solution in which I would not need to install another plugin. Can you explain this a little further? How do I actually use it?

Comment: @turzifer you can paste that code into your theme's functions.php file. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/

Comment: Yes, I already tried it, but it is not working. Do I need to rename something?

Answer (score 4):

First of all download 'Shortcodes in Menus' plugin and install/activate it.

Then in theme's function.php add following code.

```
add_shortcode( 'current-username' , 'ss_get_current_username' );
function ss_get_current_username(){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    return $user->display_name;
}
```

Now, in menu's navigation lable write `[current-username]` shortcode.

Same thing you can do for displaying avatar.

This way it will display logged in user name in menu item.